# PrimeFaces InputTextArea: Android keyboard above single page

Tags: android, jsf, primefaces, keyboard

I make a web application with JSF for a samsung tab with android 7. I have an issue with the android keyboard.
When I click on a input component, the keyboard is opening above the field. If I want to see the input field, I need to close the keyboard or tap something on the keyboard. Do you have an idea to move components when the keyboard is showing ?

Thanks.

Features :
Java, Jsf, Primefaces, Samsung tablet with Android 7.0 and Google Chrome

Comment: Is this specific to your application or in your Android phone on any website where there is an input field does this happen?  if so then it feels like a flaw in Android UI.  If its specific to your application then its possible there is a CSS trick.

Comment: Yes, this is specific of my application (i have clicked in inputtextarea of primefaces showcase and the keyboard move the component to the top).
My application have height 100% max. Can it be the problem ? Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce it just navigating to the Primefaces Showcase for InputTextArea?  https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputTextarea.xhtml

Comment: No. I don't reproduce my issue on the primefaces showcase :/

Comment: OK that tells me its something specifically with your app or CSS or something else is different if it doesn't happen with the Showcase.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My single page have max-height : 100%; perhaps this is the problem...

Comment: I find my solution. I'm using overflow: auto !important on the html component.

Comment: a good thing to do is create the answer for this explaining what the issue was and what you did to fix it and then mark it as the Accepted answer.  This way if someone else comes across they problem they will see the solution!

Comment: What you most likely did now was to create a [mcve], remove more and more until it worked. You should do that all the time in case of problems. Really helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my solution. I'm using overflow: auto !important on the html component